# RewriteCond not working to remove www. from subdomain URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.new.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

why when i enter http://www.new.domain.com is not redirected to http://new.domain.com?

The .htaccess file is in the right folder (it has more rewritecond's and they work)

Comment: Strange... despite the slightly broken regexp syntax in your RewriteCond, this _should_ work.  Are there any other RewriteRules in the .htaccess file before this one?  If so, perhaps those are interfering somehow (e.g. look for any [L] flags...)

Comment: no thats the beggining of the file... what you mean by broken regexp?

Comment: Have you tried adding a phpinfo() to your root and do a `http://www.new.domain.com/phpinfo.php` to see what value of HTTP_HOST is reported?  Your browser might have cached the 301 and is doing it locally at the client end.

Comment: In some configurations HTTP_HOST can sometimes contain a different value that the value of `Host: ...` sent in the http headers. I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp syntax in your RewriteCond is slightly broken: the correct way to test for strict equality with `www.new.domain.com` (up to differences in case) is either

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.new\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.new.domain.com [NC]
```

That said, those errors *should* not stop your rewrite rule from working: you original RewriteCond will match `www.new.domain.com` just fine, it just matches some other strings too (like `wwwXnewYdomainZcomFOOBAR`).  In fact, I have a very similar set of rules in my own `.htaccess` file, and they work just fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^vyznev\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?vyznev\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://vyznev.net/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]
```

Most of the differences between your code and mine are purely cosmetic.  The only potentially significant issue I can see if that you don't have a `RewriteBase` directive; you should definitely add one, if only to avoid potential problems later.  Still, as far as I can tell, not having one shouldn't stop you from getting at least *some* redirect, even if it might not be to the URL you expect.